# AngularJS routing always to main

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

I have the next code:

```
var app = angular.module('ForclazApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "partials/header.html"
        })
        .when("/motos", {
            templateUrl: "partials/motos.html"
        })
        .when("/repuestos", {
            templateUrl: "partials/repuestos.html"
        })
        .when("/taller", {
            templateUrl: "partials/taller.html"
        })
        .when("/blog", {
            templateUrl: "partials/blog.html"
        })
        .when("/contacto", {
            templateUrl: "partials/contacto.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Doesn't matter in which link you click, it always redirects to header.html template. I'm using AngularJS 1.6.3.
The console log doesn't show me any error.

The menu's links:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#/" class="nav-link">Inicio </a></li>
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#/motos" class="nav-link">Motos </a></li>
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#/repuestos" class="nav-link">Repuestos </a></li>
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#/taller" class="nav-link">Taller </a></li>
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#/blog" class="nav-link">Blog </a></li>
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#/contacto" class="nav-link">Contacto </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

Is basically saying that if none of the other options are matched go to to the route /. Which in your case is main. Your `.when(..` checks aren't matching the way you want them to.

In your html. Remove the / from all of your links. So it should look like this:

```
<li class="nav-li"><a href="#contacto" class="nav-link">Contacto </a></li>
```

that will match it the way you want it to.

Comment: I removed the .otherwise sentence and I've changed the href deleting the '/' character, but continues the same problem

Comment: @MarceloForclaz reason because your url , may be in your url have something like `#!` right ?

Comment: Yes! that's the problem! (!#) I've changed the version of AngularJS to 1.5.x and it works perfectly. Thanks for all. I think that if I change the "#" in links by "#!" it would works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove all `#` . And i think you should use `ui-router` instead `ng-router` .  it better for you

> https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router